# How to identify whose child has been added in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**This is a example program**

```
  public class Demo implements ChildEventListener{

      public void onCreate(Bundle b){

           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           databaseRef1.addChildEventListener(this);
           databaseRef2.addChildEventListener(this);

      }
      @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            // here i want to identify whose child has been added 
            // (databaseRef1 or databaseRef2).
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
     }
```

The above code has two `DatabaseReference` objects. Both of them have added `childEventListener`.

In onClickListener method we do something like this.

**Is there any way to differentiate like this in Firebase?**

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

       switch (view.getId()) {

           case R.id.button1: {
              return;
            }
           case R.id.button2: {
           }
    }
```

Comment: If you attach the listener to different locations, you can determine for which location it was invoked by looking at `dataSnapshot.getRef()`.

Comment: you can also use server time stamp to determin witch child added on last time

Comment: Thank you for your reply...`getRef` method returns DatabaseReference object.. how to use `switch case` there .. to perform different operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `addChildEventListener` for different locations, to see from which location the child has been added you need to check the `dataSnapshot` from `onChildAdded` method using `getRef` method like this:

```
dataSnapshot.getRef();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...`getRef` method returns DatabaseReference object.. how to use `switch case` there .. to perform different operations

Comment: Yes, that's correct, `getRef()` returns `DatabaseReference` object, but from this object you can extract the `reference`. If you have used the first reference, than `getRef()` will return a `DatabaseReference` object that indicates the first reference. The same thing is for the second. And this check can be done in `onChildAdded` method. When you use `view.getId()` means that want to get the id of the `view` that was clicked, but in this case there is no view.